# Wordpress Post featured image URL in the header

Tags: images, facebook

I want to add the featured image URL of a post to the header. When a Facebook user shares a Wordpress page, this code in the header:

The `rel="image_src"` attribute is what facebook is searching for.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="FEATUREDIMAGEURL">
```

Will return a specific image for the share. However, I cannot figure out how to add the URL of the post's featured image... Can you?

I tried this:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); ?>
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $image; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it gave me a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` error.

Comment: You're missing a bracket after `get_post_thumbnail_id();`. So it's exactly what error message tells you. Hint: There's a line number and filename _hidden_ in the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this one and point to the *real* problem:

As the `<head>` HTML tag comes far before the actual loop, you'll need something else than the `global $post`.

```
get_queried_object();
get_queried_object_id();
```

### The plugin

*The code is tested and works.*

As you might want to keep this functionality when switching themes, I'd suggest wrapping it up in a plugin.

So the actual plugin should be something around the following lines:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#70215) »kaiser« Post Thumbnail image for FB */
function wpse70215_fb_img()
{
    // Not on a single page or post? Stop here.
    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return;

    $post_ID = get_queried_object_id();

    // We got no thumbnail? Stop here.
    if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $post_ID ) )
        return;

    // Get the Attachment ID
    $att_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_ID );

    // Get the Attachment
    $att    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att_ID );

    printf(
         '<link rel="image_src" href="%s">'
        ,array_shift( $att )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse70215_fb_img' );
```

Comment: I believe that there is a form of bug in this code. I added an array here `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att_ID, array ( 578 ) );` This should prioritise images with width 578px, correct? Apparently, it seems to work sometimes but sometimes it selects a different size even though 578px version exists. Do you know why? Also, I selected this answer as correct as I ended up using this solution than the other one posted.

Comment: @AmandaDuke 578px is _some_ size. You decided to add that. What that answer shows is just a core solution... there's nothing that's decide to take a specific amount of pixels for an img.

Answer (score 2):

there was a closing bracket missing in the second line; and you need to reference the first array element of `$image`:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?> 
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?> 
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

you might also want to add a check for single post or page, to avoid any unwanted output in index or archive pages; example:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && is_singular() ): ?>
```